# Almost Noetherian module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

An $R$-module $M$ is called an *almost Noetherian* $R$-module if every proper submodule of $M$ is finitely generated.

[image]

My question is the "if" part of (ii): it says that *in order to show that $K$ is an almost Noetherian $R$-module it suffices to show that if $A$ is a proper $R$-submodule of $K$ then $SA\neq K$.* But why is it sufficient?

P.S. I only need the case when $R$ is a Discrete Valuation Ring. In that case $S=R$, so I will accept as an answer if it works in this case.

Comment: Let me mention that your excerpt is from the paper "*Rings with an almost Noetherian ring of fractions*" by Armendariz.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't understand your P.S. (which I think is already done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1721031/discrete-valuation-ring-and-finitely-generated-submodules)) I'll try to explain why it's enough $SA\neq K$.

> Let $R\subset S$ be a finite ring extension of noetherian integral domains with the same field of fractions, say $K$, and $A$ an $R$-submodule of $K$. If $SA$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, then $A$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.

$SA$ is a finitely generated $S$-module hence a finitely generated $R$-module (why?). Since $R$ is noetherian then every $R$-submodule of $SA$ is finitely generated. In particular, $A$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.

In the question one assumes $SA\ne K$. Then $SA$ is a finitely generated $S$-module. Now use the property above.